# Auto approve Facebook comments on website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-application

I'm using the [Facebook Comments Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/?fb_action_ids=844967135561793&fb_action_types=og.comments) for my website's commenting feature for articles on the website.

I notice now that all the comments are lined up for me to approve.

Is there any way/settings in the Facebook comment app that will *automatically* post comments posted by public users?

Comment: Setting Moderation to "Public" under the Moderation Rules tab [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#moderation) should make all comments automatically public, but they'll appear in the Review tab too.

Comment: Do I still have to approve every comment with your settings?

Comment: The link in my comment is to Facebook's documentation, which states that with that setting:  `All comments will be public. They'll also appear in the Review tab.` So approval for comments to be public doesn't seem necessary according to that. If that solves your issue, please add that as an answer below and accept it when you can.